# Storing data with no local storage or do an action only once (with refresh)

Tags: javascript, storage, local, store

Ok. So here's how it looks like.

When I start the app, one of the first thing I receive from server is **data**:

```
{name: "test",
 type: "checkbox"
 checked: true,
}
```

which make one of the checkboxes check. It happens every time the app starts, and after browser refresh it happens again and overrides my custom settings. So I want to use those **data** only once, when I start the app for the first time.

So I have to somehow store the data (which shouldn't disappear when refreshing the app) OR there is another way of doing this. Have been thinking of creating a new object which could store the **data** and prevent from using it if it has been used before, but browser refresh ruins everything.

Is there any way of solving that problem with no use of web storage?

Answer (score 1):

You have the "localStorage" function in JavaScript, you can use it. (explaining on this function https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp).

But I am not sure this is the best way to transport data in your app, I think it's better to do it by the server logic, You have a lot of options like passing the data on the session or to store the information on the configuration file (for example config.php).

Answer (score 0):

When you refresh a page, all changes in the browser are gone. You can recreate it only by fetching data from a DB. That DB could be either on the server side (a persistent storage) or on the client side (localstorage or sessionstorage).

If what you want is, the data should stay across page transitions, all you need is a single page applications where a page transition is not a browser refresh.

For e.g. if you use Angular, you can store the data in a service or can use a more sophisticated solution using RxJS `shareReplay`